# OpenCV findContours crash

Tags: ios, opencv

I've got this code:

```
mat.copyTo(tmpMat);
cvtColor(tmpMat, tmpMat, CV_BGR2GRAY);
cv::equalizeHist(tmpMat, tmpMat);
    cv::Mat browMat = tmpMat(eyebrowRect);
    std::vector<std::vector<Point> > contours;
    cv::findContours(browMat, contours, cv::RETR_LIST, cv::CHAIN_APPROX_NONE);
```

but it crashes with this error:

> OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (type == type0 || (CV_MAT_CN(type) == CV_MAT_CN(type0) && ((1 << type0) & fixedDepthMask) != 0)) in create, file /Users/robin/Projects/OpenCVForiPhone/opencv/opencv/modules/core/src/matrix.cpp, line 1249
>   terminate called throwing an exception

I think my Mat is already in 1-channel gray-scale because of cvtColor call...

How can I fix this?

Comment: How do you expect cvtColor work in-place for conversion from 3-channel to 1-channel image?

Comment: I'm using too cv::adaptiveThreshold that will convert to 1channel image, I think... If I'm wrong, please tell me how can I achieve a 1 channel image from my mat

Comment: @Progeny You should accept the answer if it has solved your problem

Answer (score 10):

Instead of:

```
std::vector<std::vector<Point> > contours;
```

have you tried?

```
std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point> > contours;
```

Comment: I had substituted Point for CvPoint because I didn't take the time to read the compiler error properly. Changing to cv::Point did the trick for me.